# Error in a Python Code (Import from Math - PI)

Tags: python, math, visual-studio-code

morning

I'm a beginner in python and I've tried execute the code bellow:

```
import unicodedata

print(unicodedata.lookup("GREEK SMALL LETTER PI"))
```

However, VS code reports:

```
 print(unicodedata.lookup("GREEK SMALL LETTER PI"))
  File "C:\Users\josew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03c0' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can you help me, please ?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Looks like your environment is not set up for UTF-8. What are you running on?

Comment: If you separate the lookup from the print, what is causing the error? The lookup, or the print?

Comment: Try importing the sys module in the python interpreter, then run this and tell us the output: `print(sys.stdout.encoding)`. Your code works for me in VSCode Win10

Comment: Works for me - VSCODE, Win 7.

Comment: The problem is in your system's settings, lookup function gets correct value `'\u03c0'` but print is using cp1252, not utf-8.